# Where is the flaw in my binary tree insertion logic?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

My solution is like

```
/*
Node is defined as 

typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   node * left;
   node * right;
}node;

*/


node * insert (node * root, int value)
{
   bool inTreeAlready = false;
   node * cur = root;
   while(cur != NULL)
   {
       if(cur->data < value)
           cur = cur->right;
       else if(cur->data > value)
           cur = cur->left;
       else
       {
           inTreeAlready = true;
           break;
       }
   }
   if(!inTreeAlready)
   {
       cur = new node; 
       cur->data = value;
       cur->left = NULL;
       cur->right = NULL;
   }   
   return root;
}
```

where the prompt to the problem says you're supposed to return the root of the tree after insertion.

This is evidently wrong as the output is

> ```
> Wrong Answer!
> Some possible errors:
> 1. You returned a NULL value from the function. 
> 2. There is a problem with your logic
> 3. You are printing some value from the function
> ```

which isn't very descriptive.

I've double-checked my logic and don't know what the deal is.

Comment: I see you creating a new node, but I don't see you actually linking it to the tree. It's doesn't become reachable from `root` - it's simply leaked. If you start with an empty tree (`root == NULL`), you clearly end with an empty tree, too (`root` is still `NULL`) - so you never ever get even the first node in.

Comment: That's odd that this code prints something, because it doesn't have any `printf` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the new node into the tree. Here's a modified version.

```
node * insert (node * root, int value)
{
   bool inTreeAlready = false;
   node * cur = root;
   node *parent;
   bool right;
   while(cur != NULL)
   {
       parent = cur;
       if(cur->data < value)
       {
           cur = cur->right;
           right = true;
       }
       else if(cur->data > value)
       {
           cur = cur->left;
           right = false;
       }
       else
       {
           inTreeAlready = true;
           break;
       }
   }
   if(!inTreeAlready)
   {
       cur = new node; 
       cur->data = value;
       cur->left = NULL;
       cur->right = NULL;
       if(root == NULL) root = cur;
       else if(right) parent->right = cur;
       else parent->left = cur;
   }   
   return root;
 }
```

Comment: And to think that I could've done this whole thing in 5-7 lines in C# lol. Gotta love C++.

Comment: @user7127000 Do what exactly in "5-7 lines"?  Regardless of the language used, your issue with the code is that you totally left out linking the new node with the tree.   No language would have magically made the node a part of the tree without code to do it.

Comment: @user7127000 i could make it one line (with a few semi colons in it of course). ;-) just kidding. i agree that one task seems so complicated with one language, but could be quite simple with another language.

Comment: By the way, this solution is giving a segmentation fault on one of the test cases

Comment: @user7127000 another brief look at the code, it'd have problems if root is NULL. so i modified the code. hope that'd fix the problem you encountered.